# MVC 5 DevExpress settings.BeforeExport event is not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devextreme

I have a fully working `GridView` using `DevExpress` with `MVC 5`.

I would like to add the possibility to export the data in various formats, and I've managed to do that by following some online examples.

Now, I need to hide some columns when exporting, and I've read about the `BeforeExport` property.

Here's what I've done:

```
 var grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings => {
    //blah blah stuff
     #region Export
        settings.Toolbars.Add(t => {
            t.EnableAdaptivity = true;
            t.Items.Add(GridViewToolbarCommand.ExportToXls);
            t.Items.Add(GridViewToolbarCommand.ExportToXlsx);
            t.Items.Add(GridViewToolbarCommand.ExportToCsv);
        });

        settings.SettingsExport.EnableClientSideExportAPI = true;
        settings.SettingsExport.ExcelExportMode = DevExpress.Export.ExportType.DataAware;
        settings.SettingsExport.RenderBrick = (sender, e) => {
            if (e.RowType == GridViewRowType.Data && e.VisibleIndex % 2 == 0)
                e.BrickStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE);
        };

        settings.SettingsExport.Landscape = true;
        settings.SettingsExport.BeforeExport = (sender, e) => {
            MVCxGridView gridView = sender as MVCxGridView;
            if (sender == null) return;
            gridView.Columns["myColumnFieldNameToHide"].Visible = false;
        };
    #endregion
    //blah blah other stuff
}
```

The thing is, no matter what, the callback I've set for `BeforeExport` is never executed, my guess is the event is never fired.

What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was discussed in the [official DevExpress ticket](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T582403/gridview-beforeexport-event-is-not-raised-on-exporting-data-using-gridviewtoolbarcommand).

You can find a workaround for this scenario:
Handle the ToolbarItemClick event and change the visibility of the necessary columns:

```
settings.ToolbarItemClick += (s, e) => 
{
    var gridView = s as MVCxGridView;
    if(gridView == null)
        return;
    if(e.Item.Command == GridViewToolbarCommand.ExportToXlsx) {
        gridView.Columns["Text"].Visible = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: You're a life savior. Thanks!